# Message broker wont broadcast messages

Tags: java, websocket, stomp

I have sat for hours trying to get my message broker to work, but I cannot find any solution. I have followed tutorials on youtube and on springs own webpage but nothing works. I am able to subscribe to destinations and send messages to the server, which gets recieved, but as soon as I try to send that message to either a specific client or to broadcast the message to all connected clients, nothing happens.

```
WebSocketStompClient stompClient = new WebSocketStompClient(new StandardWebSocketClient());
    stompFriendRequestsHandler = new WebsocketHandler();
    WebSocketHttpHeaders stompFriendRequestHeader = createWebsocketHeader(headerForFriendRequestStomp);

    System.out.println(stompFriendRequestHeader);

    stompClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080/ws", stompFriendRequestHeader, stompFriendRequestsHandler);

    StompSession session = stompFriendRequestsHandler.getSession();
    session.subscribe("/all/messages", new StompFrameHandler() {
        @Override
        public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
            System.out.println("getPayLoadType!");
            return String.class;
        }

        @Override
        public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
            System.out.println("YAY! We got the broadcast");
            System.out.println(payload);

        }
    });
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode objectNode = objectMapper.createObjectNode();
    objectNode.put("friendRequestUsername", 1);
    try {
        byte[] payload = objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(objectNode);
        stompFriendRequestsHandler.getSession().send("/app/application", payload);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

This code will send a message to `/app/application` and the message does get mapped to the right class and the printstatements inside the method which handles the messages gets printed.

```
@MessageMapping("/application")
@SendTo("/all/messages")
public Message send(final Message message)throws Exception{
    System.out.println("BROADCASTER");
    System.out.println(message);
    return message;
}
```

However nothing gets sent back to the client... All that happens is that `System.out.println("getPayLoadType!");` gets printed inside the `@Override public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers)` of the subscription, but nothing else.

this is my config class on the server:

```
Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com/swoosh/springbootchatapp/chatapp/friend/system/stomp/friendrequest/controller"})
public class StompConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry){
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("*");
//.setHandshakeHandler(new StompHandshakeHandler());
}

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry){
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/all", "/specific");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a queue to catch the message:

```java
    private static ArrayBlockingQueue<String> subscribe(StompSession session, String destination) {
        var queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);

        session.subscribe(destination, new StompFrameHandler() {
            @Override
            public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
                return String.class;
            }

            @Override
            @SneakyThrows
            public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
                queue.add((String) payload);
            }
        });

        return queue;
    }
```

Then the flow can be blocked somehow:

```java
var message = subscribe(session, "/all/messages");
var response = message.poll(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
assertNotNull(response);
```